# Why is ECONNREFUSED when calling AWS ApiGatewayV2 from NodeJs locally with established connectionId?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, websocket, aws-api-gateway, aws-sdk

[image: Diagram of Flow]

I have created a flow of ApiGateway that stores connectionId of all currently connected users in a DynamoDB database. I want to test by using ApiGatewayManagement ( **@aws-sdk/client-apigatewaymanagementapi** ) locally with PostToConnection in a local NodeJS file.

I have established a connection, and my connectionId has been stored and is active. I have written a script to see if I can now send a message to this connection:

```
const { ApiGatewayManagementApi } = require("@aws-sdk/client-apigatewaymanagementapi");
const api = new ApiGatewayManagementApi({ apiVersion: "2018-11-29", endpoint: "wss://REDACTED.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/prod" });

const params = {
    ConnectionId: "REDACTED",
    Data: Buffer.from(JSON.stringify({ Item: { q: "hello world" } }))
};

const run = async () => {
    return api.postToConnection(params);
};

run();
```

However, I am receiving an **ECONNREFUSED** error and I am unsure if I am leaving something out locally to authenticate to my API Gateway. I am able to do this all on AWS console, but using above test.js file locally fails. My question is: Can I use connectionId to talk directly to this connection that is actively established?

Answer (score 3):

I know, it looks strange, but please try to change endpoint from **"wss:"** to **"https:"**.

I got the same problem after migration to v3 SDK.

I use custom domain name and if previously I had to specify

```
new AWS.ApiGatewayManagementApi({
  ...,
  endpoint: 'ws.mydomain.com/endpoint'
});
```

Now it started to work only after I specified

```
new ApiGatewayManagementApi({
  ...,
  endpoint: 'https://ws.mydomain.com/endpoint'
});
```

Comment: Yeah, it worked for me. Tnx

Comment: I spent quite a bit of time trying to solve this problem. Too bad, this error could be handled automatically by the SDK.